# How to catch network errors that occurred on CAF receiver on Chrome-sender side?

Tags: google-cast

I have a basic CAF receiver application.
Assume, network error is occurred on the receiver side, during playback.
(e.g. multiple chunk requests fail, DRM license request fails etc)

I can handle these errors on the receiver side, like:

```
playerManager.addEventListener(cast.framework.events.EventType.ERROR, errorHandler);
```

but I can't find such API on the chrome-sender side.

It looks like chrome-sender have multiple "main" classes to control receiver:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/cast.framework.CastContext
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/cast.framework.CastSession
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/cast.framework.RemotePlayerController

and these classes do not have any 'error' related API

I can only wrap `session.loadMedia` to try/catch

but this still not handles errors during playback.

How sender can be notified by the receiver, that something went wrong?

I should show some error message on sender too, in such cases.